# How to display custom validation based on the field name inside a single method in AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I Have a Model like this inside my controller.js

```
$scope.model= {
            userName: { value: "", errors: [] },
            password: { value: "", errors: [] }
        };
```

I have this HTML on my view.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="item">
        <span class="dataText">Name<span class="required-field">*</span></span>
        <input class="dataItem" type="text" ng-model="model.userName.value" title="" ng-class="{errorCell: model.userName.errors.length > 0}" ng-change="validateField(model.userName)" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <span class="dataText">Password<span class="required-field">*</span></span>
        <input class="dataItem" type="password" ng-model="model.password.value" title="" ng-class="{errorCell: model.password.errors.length > 0}" ng-change="validateField(model.password)" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller method to validate any field

```
$scope.validateField = function (field) {
            field.errors = [];
            if (!field.value || field.field.trim() == "") {
                field.errors.push(------ + " is required.");
            } 
        };
```

The error message I want to push here for field "model.name" should be like "Name is required" and for field "model.password" should be "password is required".

**The question is** How would I know the **field name** (like "name" & "password") inside the method "validateField" to give a proper error message to user.

As I have many more fields to validate so I can't create a separate method for each and every field. The way I am trying to validate field is quite different because I need to perform both side validation(client side and server side).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass a string to you validateField function. With that string you can access the property on your model and you can use it to display an error message.

And to make things nice...you probably want to add a human readable property to (for example) your userName object. Let's say 'displayName' or so....You can use that in your error message then. So you only have to specify the key in your model (userName, password, etc.) as argument to your validateField function.

So in your HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.userName.value" ng-change="validateField('userName')" />
```

And your JS:

```
$scope.validateField = function (prop) {
    var field = $scope.model[prop];

    // Do your magic here.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default AngularJS form validation:
http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html

Or create custom validation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms